# Optimal compression for a large base 10 number contained in a string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, compression

I am writing compression and decompression functions for strings containing base 10 digits. I figure that, since it is a mere 10 characters being acted upon, that there exists a much smaller string that can represent large strings. The compressed result is encoded in ISO-8859-7, so I can use 256 characters in the result string

For example, I want to take a string that represents a 1000-digit number ([this one](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8), for example) and "compress it". Numbers of these lengths exceed the number type in the language that I am working in, JavaScript. As such, numeric manipulation/conversion is out of the question. The compression software I use ([shoco](https://github.com/Ed-von-Schleck/shoco)) does not compress numbers. At all.

How might I go about doing this? Is there a certain algorithm that can be used to compress numbers? I am not looking for performing speed, but rather looking for optimal compression for a majority of numbers, not just the number given as an example.

Comment: Check out list of compression algorithms somewhere (i.e. Wikipedia) and see if you like one. I.e. basic [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) likely would be good choice. When you figure out algorithm you want and tried to implement it - update post (if you still have question) so concrete recommendations can be provided. Otherwise too broad in current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work on the number in groups of three digits, you can represent each triplet in 10 bits with very little wastage. Then you "just" need to create a stream of 8-bit octets from your stream of 10-bit triples, which will require a certain amount of bit-shifting, but is not awfully complicated.

That assumes that your number consists of a multiple of 3 digits (you could pad it with leading zeros) or that you know how many digits it contains (in which case you could pad it at the end with trailing zeros). If you encoded subsequences into 50 bit units, you would have enough codespace to encode digit sequences of up to 15 digits, not just exactly 15 digits, which would avoid the need to pad. You could just barely get away with that in a language which uses 53-bit floating point as a common numeric type, but it might or might not be worth the extra complication.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you explain to me the creation of 8-bit octets... etc.? I'm not familiar with those terms. Thanks again.

Comment: (I'd like to think Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ wasn't asking about what octets are:) if 5 triplets encode as integer and split into 5 octets else if 4 triplets {encode as integer, add 2^40 (or 10^12), split}  else if 3 triplets {encode as integer, add 2^40+2^30 (or 10^12+10^9)else… 2^50 is the lowest power where this works, with 2^40 a close miss. (With a 63+1-bit ALU, 18 triplets work just as well and may be the more obvious choice)

Comment: @greybeard: OP claims to be working in javascript, which is why I suggest the 50-bit procedure. Or better said, possibility, since I didn't spell out how to do it; your suggestion is one reasonable approach.

Answer (score 3):

rici's answer, using 10 bits for every three digits, is indeed what I would use for a practical application.

However since you asked for the *optimal* compression and stated that you don't care about speed, that would be generating a binary representation of the decimal number using multiple precision arithmetic. This code has already been written for you in the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/). That library is highly optimized and quite fast, so you would not see a huge speed impact, depending on what else you're doing with the numbers.

As an example your 1000-digit number would take 418 bytes to code using 334 sets of 10 bits. It would take 416 bytes when encoded as a single, large, binary integer. On a 2 GHz i7, I get 1.9 µs for the 1000-digit conversion using sets of 10 bits, vs. 55 µs using multiple precision arithmetic to make a big integer.

*Update:*

I missed the javascript tag until someone pointed it out in a comment. You can use [Crunch](http://crunch.js.org/) for multiple-precision arithmetic in javascript.

*Update 2:*

As pointed out by rici, the comparison above assumes that the length of the input is known a priori for both encodings. However if the stream of bits needs to embedded in a larger stream and the number of digits is not known a priori, then a means must be provided to determine where the number ends.

The 10-bit encoding of three digits permits using a final 10-bit code to be that marker, since 24 of the possible values are unused. In fact, we can use 10 of those 24 to provide one more digit to the number. (We could even add a "half" digit by using 20 values for 0..19, allowing a leading 1 if present in that position. Or we could use that for sign to allow negative integers. But I digress.) This turns out to be perfect for the case of 1000 digits, which is a multiple of three, plus one. Then 1000 digits can be encoded with an end marker in 418 bytes, the same as before when not requiring an end marker. (In a stream of bits it can actually be 417.5 bytes.)

For the binary integer we can either precede it with a length in bits, or use bit stuffing to mark the end of the stream with a series of one bits. The overhead is about the same either way. We'll do the latter to make it easy to handle arbitrary-length integers. The 1000-digit integer will take 3322 bits, or 415 bytes and two bits. We can choose the maximum run of one bits in the data to be 11 long. When 11 1's appear in a row, a 0 bit is stuffed into the stream. If 12 1's are seen in a row, then you have reached the end of the stream (the 12 1's and a preceding 0 are discarded.) Using 11 will add 13 bits to the end, plus allowing up to one bit of stuffing to fill the last byte (the mean number of stuffed bits is 0.81), bringing the total bytes to 417.

So there is still gain, four bits to be precise, though less now due to the advantage of the unused 10-bit patterns.

Comment: I'm not quite sure GNU MP is for ECMAScript coders.

Comment: Ah, good point. I missed the javascript tag. I'll add a pointer to an appropriate library.

Comment: Could you include your code? I cannot get Crunch to transform my 1000 digit number, much less convert it to binary.

Comment: I don't have code, but Crunch has all you need. To make the big number, start with zero, and then for each digit multiply the number by ten and add the digit (0..9, i.e. the character minus '0'), using `add()` and `mul()`. Crunch stores the number in binary, so the byte array that is the number is your binary encoding.

Comment: It is certainly true that you can shave a tiny bit off the compressed size by using multiprecision arithmetic. But you also need to include the mechanism used to figure out where the number ends. If you know the number is exactly 1000 digits, then this takes 0 bytes, obviously, but I can encode 1000 digits as 333 10-bit segments followed by a four-bit segment for the last digit, total 3334 bits which is 2 bits short of 417 bytes. For an indeterminate length, I can do it with maximum 16 bits of overhead (maybe less); only for *very* big numbers would a length+MP number be shorter.

Comment: For arbitrary length you'll never have to add more than 10 bits, and you might get an extra digit or two out of it to boot. See the update in my answer.